# Change button state located in style resources from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I can't located a button which I defined in my mainpage resources and in a style. I after accessing that button, I want to change its visual state to pressed. This is what I tried in codebehind(MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
private void OnShowPopupButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.myPopup.IsOpen = !this.myPopup.IsOpen;

        //attempt at accessing button resource to change state
        if ((this.myPopup.IsOpen))
        {
            this.HomeButton.Controls.Style = this.Resources["PivotStyle1"] as Style;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(HomeButton, "Pressed", true);
        }
    }
```

And the hierarchy of where HomeButton is located(in MainPage.xaml) is as follows:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
         ...
         <Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="controls:Pivot">
              ....
              <Setter Property="Template">
              ...
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Pivot">
                ...
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button x:Name="HomeButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Click="OnShowPopupButtonClick" >
.....
.....
```

And here is where I call out my style in the layoutroot:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <controls:Pivot x:Name="MainPivotControl" Title="MyApp" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" FontFamily="myFont">
...
...
```

So when I attempt to build the app, an error message pops up saying HomeButton does not exist in the current context. Another error message says it has no definition or extension method. Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong in the code behind? It's been days I've been browsing the web and going through some tutorials, and none were of help.
Thanks

---

EDIT: Here is my code as suggested by user "nit": But breakpoints show that HomeButton is still not found.

```
private void OnShowPopupButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.myPopup.IsOpen = !this.myPopup.IsOpen;

        //attempt at accessing button resource to change state
        if ((this.myPopup.IsOpen))
        {
            //This section will help locate and assign HomeButton then event function will launch
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MainPivotControl); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MainPivotControl, i);
                if (child is Button)
                {
                    var myHomeButton = child as Button;
                    //This is where the event procedure will be given
                    if (myHomeButton.Name == "HomeButton")
                    {
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(myHomeButton, "Pressed", true);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //This section will help locate and assign HomeButton then event function will launch
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(MainPivotControl); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MainPivotControl, i);
                if (child is Button)
                {
                    var myHomeButton = child as Button;
                    //This is where the event procedure will be given
                    if (myHomeButton.Name == "HomeButton")
                    {
                        VisualStateManager.GoToState(myHomeButton, "Pressed", false);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Loaded event on your button and save the sender parameter in a field which will be your button.

```
//button can be reused everywhere (including inside your OnShowPopupButtonClick function)
Button myPopupButton;

public myPopupButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
    myPopupButton=sender as Button;
    if ((this.myPopup.IsOpen))
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(myPopupButton, "Pressed", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the loaded event. So the button should be the object sender correct? In the button loaded event function, how would I access/change/save its parameters like the visualstate then? Any guide/tutorial would be helpful. Thanks.
my loaded function:
    private void myPopupButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

Comment: Thanks this was of great help. I wanted one of my buttons to stay pressed but I found out I just had to change the type of button to a ToggleButton, now it all works well!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your HomeButton like this as it is not the variable defined directly for your window class. In order to access that you will have to search that in visual tree of Pivot control like below:

```
 public Button FindButton(DependencyObject parent)
 {
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;

    Button homeButton = null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        Button button = child as Button;
        if (button == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            homeButton = FindButton(child);

            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (homeButton != null) break;
        }
        else
        {
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (button.Name == "HomeButton")
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                homeButton = button;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return homeButton;
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and modified the function a bit. No errors so far but even with the debug breakpoint inside the if statement where HomeButton is found, the breakpoint doesn't fire. Hence it still cannot find the HomeButton and the button state condition won't apply. See the EDIT, for updated code. Thanks

Comment: buddy you will have to recursively search for your button in the visual tree.. i gave you just an example.. if you child is not button then you will have to go into the visual tree of that child to find it..if not found then you will go to next sibling..

Comment: updated the answer.. you can use this function to return your homebutton...you will have to pass the Pivot control MainPivotControl as param

Comment: I have used Benoit's way to change state. But I will attempt your suggestion as soon as I can since I'm sure will come in handy at some point. Thanks for the help!